# How to search a tweets with effects similar to this website:Monitter

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am trying to search a tweets using search method in twitter4j with 
effects similar to this website:Monitter.com

Like this website, I want to display a tweets in real time twitter 
updates. I just want the tweets to be loaded in a similar manner. 
So how do i search tweets in similar to this website(Monitter.com)?

Please could someone show me a simple query examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you already know how to use the twitter4j examples. If you look at the `SearchTweets.java` file under "twitter4j-2.2.5\twitter4j-examples\src\main\java\twitter4j\examples\search", the following code will be relevant to you:

```
try {
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query(args[0]));
    List<Tweet> tweets = result.getTweets();
    for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
        System.out.println("@" + tweet.getFromUser() + " - " + tweet.getText());
    }
    System.exit(0);
} catch (TwitterException te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

For real-time updating like Monitter, you should encase this chunk in a loop that runs at regular intervals (check out `Thread.sleep()`). Next, you may want to shorten the number of results retrieved based on your frequency. For that, open up `Query.java` under "twitter4j-2.2.5\twitter4j-examples\src\main\java\twitter4j". The default Query for `SearchTweets.java` uses only a String argument, but you'll want to look at the `setRpp()` and `setSince()` methods.

I'm still new to this too so I can't be certain about it, but I hope my answer helps! I'd have commented instead but I don't have sufficient privileges.